# How to start with speeddial mozilla extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I want to create extension that replaces the blank page with my content
(static links plus data via ajax/iframe requests)
How should I start, where I can found usefull documentation? How can I
separate tab state when tab is blank or when tab is showing some website.

Is such code enough for minimal example

```
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" id="speeddialOverlay">
    <window id="main-window">
            <vbox id="speeddial-multikey-wrapper">
                 <iframe src="http://www.somesite.com"></iframe>
            </vbox>
    </window>
</overlay>
```

Comment: Firefox doesnt have blank page anymore. It has a speed dial of its own. But if you still want to make your custom one see these addons: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=speed+dial&appver=26.0&platform=windows